# How can I reset AirPort Express to factory defaults?

Tags: iphone, airport

I tried the, press reset and power it down without success. All I got was to make it do yellow blinking. If I release the reset the blinking slops, anyways it stops even without releasing the button after 30 seconds.

The problem is that AirPort utility is not able to detect it and no Wireless is started.

What else should I try to reset this white brick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the full procedure is

1. Unplug the unit
2. Press and hold reset (e.g. with paper clip)
3. Plug the unit back into power outlet (while pressing reset)
4. Wait for rapid green flashing
5. Release reset button

From your description, it's not clear how you were managing the AC power

Comment: This is the correct way and the important steps are 2 and 3. You have to give it 10 secs of "reset" on each (or until you get the green flashing in step 4)

Comment: I anly get yellow flashing light instead of green :p

Comment: Are you sure you have to disconnect the unit from the AC power?

Comment: The steps worked for me: Unplug, hold reset for 10 seconds, plug in with reset still held, hold reset for another 10 seconds.